# Unable to connect to DynamaDB DAX Cluster from ECS Cluster

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, spring-webflux, aws-dax

I'm trying to connect to DynamoDB DAX Cluster using DynamoDBAsynClient that runs from ECS Cluster, I get **

> java.io.IOException: Channel was closed before it could be written to

** while establishing the connection

Below is the cluster client configuration

```
  @Bean
    public DynamoDbAsyncClient getDynamoDbAsyncClient() throws IOException {


        software.amazon.dax.Configuration configuration = software.amazon.dax.Configuration.builder()
                .url(dynamoDbDaxEndPointUrl)
                  .region(Region.of(awsRegion)).build();
        return ClusterDaxAsyncClient.builder()
                .overrideConfiguration(configuration)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient getDynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient(DynamoDbAsyncClient dynamoDbAsyncClient) {
        return DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient.builder()
                .dynamoDbClient(dynamoDbAsyncClient)
                .build();
    }
```

I tried tweaking timeout configuration, still get same error. Anyone has any input with this issue?

Comment: This code doesn't seem valid, specifically `..build()`.

Comment: that was a typo, i updated it

Comment: Have you modified the timeouts at all, or are you getting the exception with default values also? Have you network connectivity on your DAX port 8111?